# How to change the color of a specific cell in a JTable (JAVA)?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

well my question is how to change the color of a specific cell in a JTable in Java? as far as I know the first thing I should do is to override the method CellRendered I have already did this part as follows:

```
public class CustomTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer 
{
    int amount;
    int f,c;

    public CustomTableCellRenderer(int a)
    {

        amount = a;


    }
    public CustomTableCellRenderer()
    {




    }
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
   (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
   boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
   {
    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent
    (table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    if(amount == 3)
    {

            cell.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    }
    if(amount == 1)
    {

        cell.setBackground(Color.cyan);

    }
    if(amount == 2)
    {

        cell.setBackground(Color.orange);

    }


    return cell;
 }
```

}

And when I want to change the color of the cell, I change the color but it changes the whole column, the part of the code where I used the override goes as follows:

```
 Cache_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columna).setCellRenderer(new    CustomTableCellRenderer(1));
```

How can I specify the exact position of the cell  I want to change the color, specifying the number of row and column:

Eg:

new CustomTableCellRenderer(int row, int column);

Is that possible?

Thanks guys¡¡

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `else if` statements and then adding a default value in the default last else block.

Also, and **this is key**, don't set amount in the renderer's constructor -- that won't work. Instead you must get the amount result inside of the `getTableCellRendererComponent` method, usually from the cell's value, or from the value from another model cell on the same row.

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
   (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
   boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererCo

    // check that we're in the right column
    if (column != correctColumn) { 
        // if not the right column, don't change cell
        return cell;       
    }

    // SomeType is the type of object held in the correct column
    SomeType someType = (SomeType) value;

    if (value == null) {
        value = "";
        return cell;       
    }

    // and hopefully it has a method for getting the amount of interest
    int amount = someType.getAmount();

    if(amount == 3) {
            cell.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    } else if(amount == 1) {
        cell.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    } else if(amount == 2) {
        cell.setBackground(Color.orange);
    } else {
        cell.setBackground(null); // or a default background color
    }
```

Also, you might need to be sure that your cell is opaque.